# Sprite Kit is resizing an image and altering the aspect ratio

Tags: ios, image, sprite-kit, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to add a background sprite in Sprite Kit using the Xcode 6 Beta, the image size is 1136 by 640 pixels, the size of the iPhone screen in landscape. Because the deployment target of the app is iOS 7.0 and higher, I can't use the Images.xcassets catalog (it doesn't show the images in anything lower than iOS 8). When I run the project on either my device (iPhone 5s on iOS 7.1.1) or the iOS 8 simulator, the image is stretched to be wider and shorter than the screen despite identical resolutions.

I can't help but feel this may be an issue with Xcode 6 or because I'm not using the image catalog. Below is my code and a screenshot:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView!) {
  let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Loading.png")
  background.zPosition = -1
  background.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
  self.addChild(background)
}
```

[image: Distorted image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, this has really been frustrating me.

Comment: scene scaleMode, change it to aspect fit or resize fill